# Joining or concatenating two different vectors into a one vector

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have one vector $x = (x_0, ..., x_n)$ and another one which is $y = (y_0, ..., y_n)$, how would I correctly write what is $(x_0, ..., x_n, y_0, ..., y_n)$? Is there some symbol for this kind of concatenation? Or should I write something like $(x, y)$ or $[x, y]$?

Comment: (x,y) is a good notation.

Comment: if $x\in V$ and $y\in W$ (possibly $V=W$) then your concatenation is a vector in the cartesian product of $V$ times $W$ (i.e. insiemistic cartesian product with the linear structure defined by components). Usual notations for elements in a product of two structures is $(x,y)$ or $<x,y>$

Answer (score 1):

I would write $(x,y)=(x_0, \dots , x_n, y_0, \dots, y_n)$ the first time, and indicated to the reader that from now on this is what $(x,y)$ is going to mean.